# Is there a smart way to duplicate a Stack(Of ...)

Tags: vb.net, stack, compiler-services

In vb.net, I'm trying to create an extension to duplicate/reverse/merge stacks.
Please note that it might exists already but I'm facing an issue.

I've a module, called utility.vb that hold a whole bunch of *<Extension()>* like the Duplicate that I'm trying to write.

```
''' <summary>
''' Duplicate a stack of object to another
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T">Object type in the stack</typeparam>
''' <param name="s">Stack to duplicate</param>
''' <returns></returns>
<Extension()>
Public Function Duplicate(Of T)(ByVal s As Stack(Of T())) As Stack(Of T())
    Dim tmp As New Stack(Of T())
    For i As Integer = s.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        tmp.Push(s(i))
    Next
    Return tmp
End Function
```

I'm doing a various amount of Push in a Stack called labelStack. But when I call the Duplicate function from my code (because I need to re-use the same stack multiple times), it is not compiling (please note that the stack is made of own created object class)

```
Dim summaryStack As Stack(Of CCNode) = labelStack.Duplicate()
```

The error is *"'Duplicate' is not a member of 'Stack(Of MyForm.CCNode)'"*

I also tried to change the signature of the extension like so:

```
Public Function Duplicate(Of T As {New})(ByVal s As Stack(Of T())) As Stack(Of T())
```

But without any success.

Can someone help me (pointing out my mistake, correcting it or give me a way to achieve my need without writing the function myself)?

P.S.: I'm using Stack because I need to Pop in reverse order of my Push and it seemed appropriate.

Comment: Based on your method declaration, you need to pass in a stack of arrays of T and you get back a stack of arrays of T. I doubt that that was what you wanted. See my answer for a correct declaration, assuming I understand your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it all wrong. If you want to reuse or reverse or any such thing then you should not be creating a `Stack(Of T)` to start with. Create either an array or a `List(Of T)`, depending on whether you want be able to adjust the content, and then you can create as many `Stack(Of T)` and `Queue(Of T)` objects as you want from that. Both of those classes have a constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable(Of T)` as an argument so you can pass your array or `List(Of T)` to as many of those constructors as you like, e.g.

```vb
Dim items = {1, 2, 3, 4}
Dim s1 As New Stack(Of Integer)(items)
Dim s2 As New Stack(Of Integer)(items.Reverse())
Dim q1 As New Queue(Of Integer)(items)
Dim q2 As New Queue(Of Integer)(items.Reverse())
```

That said, I just did this:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StackExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function Copy(Of T)(source As Stack(Of T)) As Stack(Of T)
        Dim newStack As New Stack(Of T)

        For Each item In source.Reverse()
            newStack.Push(item)
        Next

        Return newStack
    End Function

End Module
```

and it worked exactly as you want. I expected the input stack to be empty after that, as I thought that enumerating a `Stack(Of T)` would pop each item but, apparently, it doesn't.

Actually, I just realised that that means that the `Stack(Of T)` constructor will accept another `Stack(Of T)` as an argument, which makes the extension method even simpler:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StackExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function Copy(Of T)(source As Stack(Of T)) As Stack(Of T)
        Return New Stack(Of T)(source.Reverse())
    End Function

End Module
```

That's so simple that I don't think that an extension method is even worth bothering with.

All that said, I'd still go with the array or `List(Of T)` as a single source of truth and create all the stacks from that. That way you can't possibly pop an item before you've created all the copies you need.

Comment: I'm used to List(Of ...) but never sure that it will keep my order of adding elements.
I'll have a look at Queue(Of ...) too but it is FIFO when I needed LIFO. It is always interesting to learn a new container anyway.

Comment: Given that you can access items in a `List(Of T)` by index, you can be sure that the order  will remain consistent. I just mentioned `Queue` because it works similarly, not because you should necessarily use it in this case.